# What is difference between these two type of List copy

Tags: python, list

```
nLst1 = ['A','B','C','D']

nLst2 = nLst1

# And

nLst3 = nLst1[:]
```

Comment: `nLst2 = nLst1` **is not a copy**. That's the difference.

Comment: look at the result of calling [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) on each of the lists. For 1 and 2 its equal for 3 its not.

Answer (score 0):

`nLst2 = nLst1` makes `nLst2` point to the same memory as `nLst1`, which means that modifying the contents of one array will modify the other:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1
list2[0] = 3
list1 # [3, 2, 3]
```

However, `nLst3 = nLst1[:]` makes a copy of `nLst1`, so the 2 arrays are disjoint:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1[:]
list2[0] = 3
list1 # still [1, 2, 3]
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/5923139).

Answer (score 0):

First one is not copy, it will point both lost to same memory address, and the second one will copy. If the first one is implemented, then changing one will affect another. The second will define a new slice copy of the list that will point to diferent memory address, you can do it using `list.copy()` too, and they will both take `O(n)`